# Simple program User input Driven

Tags: python

This program works partially. The part that i cannot get to work is combining the functions under a class. All i am looking for is to have a user input set float variable and compare it with a raw float variable from a temp sensor. I want to set a temperature (target) value THEN run a loop of temp reading in the background.

I am VERY new to programming. I have been reading alot but dont understand why the variable temp_c when under a class still comes up as not defined ? 
How do i combine this program so that every variable is defined and i have one loop running after the temperature target is set.

After running program i see:

```
Enter Temp:22 Traceback (most recent call last):   
File    "/home/pi/Desktop/Trial 1.py", line 16, 
in <module>    class HotTub:  
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/Trial 1.py", line 40, in HotTub    
temp_c=read_temp()   
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Trial 1.py", line 27, in read_temp    
lines = read_temp_raw() NameError: name 
'read_temp_raw' is not defined
```

First code sample does not work, second does. :

```
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) 
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

class HotTub:

    target=float(input("Enter Temp:" ))

    def read_temp_raw():
            f = open(device_file, 'r')
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            return lines

    def read_temp():
        lines = read_temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
            time.sleep(0.2)
            lines = read_temp_raw()
            equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
            temp_c =float(temp_string) / 1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c

    while True:
        try:
            temp_c=read_temp()
            if temp_c>=target:
                    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
                    print ('Temp is higher than',target,temp_c)

            else:
                    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
                    print ('Temp is lower than',target,temp_c)
                    time.sleep(0.5)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("W: interrupt received, stopping…")         
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print ("Exit")
```

---

```
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) # Set pin 16 to be an output pin and set initial value to low (off)
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c =float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c


def compare_temp():
    temp_c=read_temp()
    a=float(22)
    if temp_c>a:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
        print ('Temp is higher than 22',temp_c)

    else:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
        print ('Temp is lower than 22',temp_c)
        time.sleep(0.5)
while True:
    try:
        compare_temp()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("W: interrupt received, stopping…")         
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print ("Exit")
```

Comment: What benefit is the class here?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert module (2nd sample ) code to a class (1st) you need to call function via its class instance

so read_temp_raw() call becomes self.read_temp_raw() in class body or

```
#
myinstance = HotTub()
myinstance.read_temp_raw() 
#
```

Classes are namespaces and can hold lot of objects, you could adress 
variables the same way eg:

```
self.temp_c = some_value
```

or

```
print(myinstance.temp_c)
```

Comment: So to recap. I should not be or need to use a class. Thank you for your input. Do you see me being able to do what I explained without using a class. Where should i place my input line of code so that it runs first and is not part of the loop but also triggers the loop after an input is placed. The float variable of the input line has to be recognized by the loop function. How do i accomplish that with a global variable ?

Comment: first correct your class code, then maybe flow of program will be more clear. Actually it is not. eg while True: block should be in a function.